# show / hide textarea changes its height

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

Click on `ŞHOW / HIDE` several times.
You'll see that after each click textarea becomes more and more higher.
What is the reason and how to avoid this.
I need the textarea always to fit the content.

```js
$('#btna').on('click', function(){
$('#txa').hide()
});

$('#btnb').on('click', function(){
$('#txa').show()
let a = $('#txa').prop('scrollHeight');
$('#txa').height(a);
});
```

```css
#txa, #txb{
display:block;
width:100%;
resize:none;
overflow:hidde;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='txa'>
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
</textarea>

<button id='btnb'>SHOW</button>
<button id='btna'>HIDE</button>
```

Comment: for what is the height change? if you delete that, it works perfectly.

Comment: @CristianS., what to delete?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

```js
$('#btna').on('click', function(){
$('#txa').hide()
});

$('#btnb').on('click', function(){
$('#txa').show()
});


autosize();
function autosize(){
    var text = $('#txa');

    text.each(function(){
        $(this).attr('rows',1);
        resize($(this));
    });

    text.on('input', function(){
        resize($(this));
    });
    
    function resize ($text) {
        $text.css('height', 'auto');
        $text.css('height', $text[0].scrollHeight+'px');
    }
}
```

```css
#txa, #txb{
display:block;
width:100%;
resize:none;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='txa' name="md-content">
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
sdf
sdf
sdf
sdf
sdf
sdf
s
</textarea>

<button id='btnb'>SHOW</button>
<button id='btna'>HIDE</button>
```

Comment: The textAreaAdjust looks dirty and like black magic. Unless you can explain those numbers, I wouldnt recommend that solution.

Comment: I just added it, it case you need to update height dynamically while adding content, let me edit it.

Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @qadenza it just adds `row` attribute to it and increment it by 1

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, the height manipulation was unnecessary.

```js
$('#btna').on('click', function(){
$('#txa').hide()
});

$('#btnb').on('click', function(){
$('#txa').show()
});
```

```css
#txa, #txb{
display:block;
width:100%;
resize:none;
overflow:hidde;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='txa'>
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
</textarea>

<button id='btnb'>SHOW</button>
<button id='btna'>HIDE</button>
```

Comment: Thats not the problem your OP describes.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following 2 lines from your script

```
let a = $('#txa').prop('scrollHeight');
$('#txa').height(a);
```

It still works and does not add an extra line in the textarea field.